# How to get maximum number and name from 2 columns? (Excel)

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, max

I have this (example):

```
Luffy     320

Coby      350

Zoro      180
```

Now I want to show the max from this info, with number and text (in seperate cells) like this:

```
col 1     col 2   col 3
1st     350     Coby

2nd     320     Luffy

3rd     180     Zoro
```

The 2nd Column no problem with the `MAX()` formula.

For the 3rd column to get the text I've tried the `MAX(...)` and `INDEX(...)` formulas but nothings working ...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get which value is the largest, second largest and so on.
You can use the function LARGE(range, n) for this.

So in your col 2 use this formula:

```
=LARGE(B:B,1)
=LARGE(B:B,2)
=LARGE(B:B,3)
```

Assuming B is the column with the values.

Then we need to match this value and get the name

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("the above calculated cell",B:B,0))
```

With the above calculated cell I mean the LARGE function cell. And assuming column A is the column with the names.

This should give you a dynamic table that will update when values or names change.

I'm not sure how you manage to get that column 2 using MAX formula since it only outputs the largest number of the inputs and thus can't output 2nd and 3rd position.

Comment: Thank you! This works and it keeps updating as i change values :D